# ending of (jQuery,this);

Tags: jquery

I saw many js minified files having the structure:

```
(function($,window) ...... )(jQuery,this);
```

what is with this structure? It's like divided into 2 pairs of parantheses, the very big first one, and the (jQuery,this); in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an immediately executed function, and is used in this case as a closure to encase all code within a scope, rather than polluting the global environment.

Like any function, an immediately executed one can receive arguments. So it is here; the first argument is the global `jQuery` object, while the second one is the outer context, `window`.

See [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Answer (score 0):

It's an [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). Very common in JavaScript.

Comment: thx, I'll add this to the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

`(function($,window) ...... )(jQuery,this);`

The whole thing is IIFE which sends `jQuery` object to be used as a dollar sign inside the IIFE

The other parameter is (in browser environment) the `window` object which is `this` (in global scope).

The main goal is to use `$` and `window` inside the function *without* the fear that something was overwritten.

It is all done in the IIFE which creates its *own* scope which is *not* polluting the global scope.

Also

There is another trick to send nothing as an undefined parameter